# # added to URL when clicking link_to_add OR link_to_remove_association

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-6, cocoon-gem

I'm using Rails 6 and I'm trying to make nested_fields work. I'm using Cocoon. There is no JS error, JQuery is correctly loaded. The nested_form loads the nested data correctly, but I'm unable to add a new line or remove an existing line. This is my code:

In _form.html.erb

```
<div id="entry_links">
     <%= f.fields_for :entry_links do |ff| %>
          <%= render 'entry_link_fields', f: ff %>
     <% end %>  
</div>    
<div id="links">
     <%= link_to_add_association '<span class="oi" data-glyph="plus" title="icon name" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Link '.html_safe, f, :entry_links, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

_entry_link_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class = "field row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <%= f.text_field :link_type, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= f.text_field :label, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= f.text_field :link, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <%= f.number_field :line, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <%= link_to_remove_association '<span class="oi" data-glyph="trash" title="icon name" aria-hidden="true"></span>'.html_safe, f, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Just in case, here's a snippet of my package.json file which lists jQuery and coocon

```
{
     "cocoon-js": "^0.0.5",
     "jquery": "^3.5.1",
}
```

I've tried with both `@nathanvda/cocoon` AND `cocoon-js-vanilla` to no avail.

The only thing that happens when I click either of those links is that a "#" is added to the URL box. I read in another answer that it might be related to a JQuery error but that's not my case since my JS log doesn't show any error and I'm able to call other JQuery functions correctly from within the same app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that everything was correct, except I completely missed this line:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

After adding that line to my application.html.erb file, everything is correctly loaded and my links are working as expected.